# No error but data not inserted to database by using PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration form that use PDO to insert the data into database.

This is my html file;

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYOKJx

This is my insert.php file

```html
<?php
//insert.php;

if(isset($_POST["cname"]))
{
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", "testing", "pass");
 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["cname"]); $count++)
 {  
  $query = "INSERT INTO guest 
  (cname, sex, ic, age, nationality, phone, e_phone, address, check_in, check_out,remarks) 
  VALUES (:cname, :sex, :ic, :age, :nationality, :phone, :e_phone, :address, :check_in, :check_out, :remarks)
  ";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':cname'  => $_POST["cname"][$count], 
    ':sex' => $_POST["sex"][$count],
    ':ic'  => $_POST["ic"][$count], 
    ':age' => $_POST["age"][$count],
    ':nationality'  => $_POST["nationality"][$count], 
    ':phone' => $_POST["phone"][$count],
    ':e_phone'  => $_POST["e_phone"][$count], 
    ':address' => $_POST["address"][$count],
    ':check_in'  => $_POST["check_in"][$count], 
    ':check_out' => $_POST["check_out"][$count],
    ':remarks'  => $_POST["remarks"][$count]
   )
  );
 }
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 if(isset($result))
 {
  echo 'ok';
 }
}
?>
```

I couldn't find any error in error log but when I check my database, the data was not inserted.

What should I change to make it works?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to post the db name, username and pwd on a public site. However, since it's a localhost, you might be able to get away with it. Just don't do that in the future.

Comment: try `if($statement->execute(array('parameters'))) echo 'ok'; else echo $statement->errorInfo();` to get the insert error

Comment: Not sure you're binding the data correctly. I've never seen it done that way before. That doesn't necessarily mean it's wrong, but you might want to double check. You can also use (I want to say it's) $statement->bind() instead.

Comment: You cannot use `fetchAll()` on an `INSERT` statement

Comment: No errors you say? Add `$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` immediately after the `new PDO(...)` line and watch the fireworks

Comment: Prepared statements are best prepared **before** looping

Comment: i tried your code and its working perfectly on my end, i can see records in DB too, check that you fill all the fields.

Comment: I have used PDO before this to insert the data into database, it is working fine but suddenly it stop inserted into database a few days before. I didn't modified my code either.

Comment: Is the script actually managing to connect to the database (any changes to the database server)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing :

```
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
if (isset($result)) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

to

```
if ($statement->fetchAll()) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

because it seems that your `isset($result)` is not executing the command.

Comment: The `isset($result)` is totally redundant, therefore these two code snippets are functionally equivalent